# Singly linked list append method

Tags: java, addition

hey guys i am having trouble trying to implement the appened method for singly linked list.
here is the code:

```
public void append ( int item ) {
//inserts item to the end of the list
        if ( head == null){
            head = new LinkInt();
            curr = head;
            curr.elem = item;
        }
        else{
        LinkInt temp = head;
        while ( temp.next != null){
        temp = temp.next;}
        temp.elem = item;
        }


}
```

and here is my print method ( not sure if its correct as well ):

```
public void print () {
//outprint the array 
    //ie. <1, 2, |3, 4>
    if (  head == null) {
        System.out.print("<");
        System.out.print(">");
    }
    else{
    LinkInt temp = head;
    System.out.print("<");
    while ( temp != null) {
        if ( temp == curr){
                System.out.print( "|" + temp.elem + ","); }
        else{
        System.out.print( temp.elem );
        System.out.print(",");}
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    System.out.print(">");
    }
}
```

}

heres the problem:

let say appened 3 ->>> i get <|3>
but if i do appened 5 after ->>>> i get <|5> which delete my first item.

Help me out please :(

Comment: Why not store the reference to the tail element. Would make things quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkInt temp = head;
while ( temp.next != null){
    temp = temp.next;
}
temp.elem = item;
```

What this does is - `temp.next is null` when `3` is already inserted. Hence, it goes to `temp.elem = item` and overwrites your existing value. Do something like this:-

```
LinkInt temp = head;
while ( temp.next != null){
    temp = temp.next;
}
//temp.elem = item; -Not needed.

temp1= new LinkInt();
temp1.elem = item;
temp1.next = null;
temp.next = temp1;
```

Comment: Why the downvote, this answer seems right to me ? Any explaination why it's wrong, so that I too can clear my doubts :-)

Comment: i meant to click the check but i click the downvote by accident :( sorry, 1 more question how do i modify my print() so that after the last element without the comma? :D

Comment: @user2059472 : You can add another condition, for this I guess, like `if (temp.next == null) System.out.print(temp.elem + ">") else System.out.print(temp.elem + ", ")`

Comment: @user2059472 - You can click the `downvote` again to undo it:)

Answer (score 1):

after these statement :

```
while ( temp.next != null)
{
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

do this:

```
tmp1= new LinkInt();
tmp1.elem = item;
tmp1.next = null

tmp.next = tmp1
```

instead of this:

```
temp.elem = item;
```

try this for print method:

```
public void print () 
{
    //outprint the array 
    //ie. <1, 2, |3, 4>
    if (  head == null) 
    {
        System.out.print("<");
        System.out.print(">");
    }
    else
    {
        LinkInt temp = head;
        System.out.print("<");
        while ( temp->next != null) 
        {
            System.out.print( "|" + temp.elem + ","); 
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.print("|" + temp.elem);}
        System.out.print(">");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1 more question how do i modify my print() so that after the last element without the comma? :D

Comment: I have edited my answer to include print(). Check out if it works out right. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have the method this way

```
public void append(int item)  
{  
    LinkInt l = new LinkInt();  
    l.elem = item;  
    if ( head == null )  
        head = l;  
    else {  
        LinkInt tmp = head;  
        while ( tmp.next != null)  
            tmp = tmp.next;  
        tmp.next = l;  
}
```

Comment: You not adding anything to the next part of the node, to the newly created node, I guess you are assuming that `new LinkInt()` actually gives a node with a `null` value to it's `next` part.